# command line building from C#

Tags: c#

I would like to make a C# app, that automatize .cs files building, using cmd.exe. I've learned that a line like this "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\FrameWork\v3.5\csc.exe /target:exe +.cs file's location" builds the file, and that works fine manually of course. How ever from a C# code i haven't managed to build any yet.

Can somebody please help in this problem? Or is there another way this is done?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about **msbuild**. It's Microsoft's official tool for that.

Comment: If you wanna do from command line, its as @AndreCalil said. If you want to compile c# code from another c# code check this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's always `Proces.Start(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(String.Format(@"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\FrameWork\v3.5\csc.exe /target:exe {0}", filepath)));`